# Generate a single PDF from a websites HTML pages

Tags: pdf, html, wget

Here's the problem: There's a website that I often need for reference and I would like an offline version that also works in mobile devices, a PDF comes to mind.

I can make an offline copy of the HTML version with wget, that's not a the problem.

What I'd really like is a way to transform all the HTML pages into a single PDF with the internal links still working. So, a link that would have referred to another URL on the web version should then refer to the corresponding page in the PDF.

Ideally there should also be a way to generate a table of content to put into the PDF.

How can I achieve this?

Bash/Python/ruby/whatever scripts and other command line stuff are welcome, too.

(I'm on OSX 10.9 by the way.)

Comment: PDF on mobile devices are pretty horrible in my opinion. You may be a whole lot better off keeping it in the HTML format that you get from wget as properly created HTML will automatically resize gracefully to the screen. If it is still keeping the full size, then it will be the same with PDF, you'd be stuck on that screen size while working on a tiny screen.

Comment: A PDF will be just fine in this case since it's going to be read mostly on an iPad. ePub would also be fine, though. Anything that can be loaded into the iBooks app.

Comment: I still have issues with PDF on iBook but I guess that is personal opinion. Not sure how to transfer HTML into iPad readable format but the closest thing to do offline pages reading is using an App called "Pocket" (was Read it Later) but I am not sure if they do the whole website, but they do pages.

Comment: No, Pocket or Instapaper are only for single pages. I need a whole site with lots of pages.

Comment: Did you look at Calibre or Sigil. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/252127/convert-web-pages-to-one-file-for-ebook). I haven't tried but Calibre should be able to make an eBook from multiple Htmls if they are linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), a free tool which, judging from the list of advanced features advertised in its [manual page](http://madalgo.au.dk/%7Ejakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html), should at least roughly satisfy you:

> Printing more then one HTML document into a PDF file.
>
> Running without an X11 server.
>
> Adding a document outline to the PDF file.
>
> Adding headers and footers to the PDF file.
>
> Generating a table of contents.
>
> Adding links in the generated PDF file.
>
> Printing using the screen media-type.
>
> Disabling the smart shrink feature of webkit.